# Creating a static view in WPF that won't get initialized every time

Tags: wpf, user-interface, mvvm, user-controls, contentpresenter

I'm working on a WPF application that contains a wrapper UI that is actually the MainWindow.xaml and the content in it (ContentPresenter) gets changed each time the user chooses to move to a different section of the application.

When the user returns to the main content, I want the application not to initialize it each time, but to preserve it in the memory somehow and restore it when the user clicks on the "Home" button.

In its current state, the Home view gets initialized over and over again when moving back to the "Home" section, which causes the application to be kinda slow. My question is this: Is there a way to preserve that user control in the memory somehow so that I would be able to restore it fast?

Thanks!

Comment: Little hard to follow exactly what you are trying to do, but couldn't you keep the "home" content in a separate control and just hide it?

Comment: The content that is being replaced according to the buttons the user presses is actually bound to a `ContentPresenter` in the MainWindow.xaml, when the user click another workflow button, the content gets replaced to the one that was clicked by the user, but I want the "Home" content to hide and not get disposed and rebuilt each time the user returns to the "Home" screen. How can I hide it without disposing it if I'm using binding?

Comment: You can't just save the UserControl in a private variable?

Comment: Nope, it still initializes it when you rebind to it in the UI

Comment: Please post the code where you rebind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I decided to move the `ContentControl` into an `ItemsControl` and then just hide all content controls except for the active one.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModels}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Grid />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentControl Visibility="{Binding Visibility}" Content="{Binding ViewModel}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

In my ViewModel I have the actual content and another `Visibility` property that is set to `false` when the content is not the current one and `true` if it is.

Thanks to all helpers!

Comment: As stated above, I've fixed this issue with that workaround. Thanks to all you helpers! :)

Answer (score 1):

Hiding is an option ofcourse as @Matt suggested. An other way is to explorer the wonderfull world of frameworks (Prism, Caliburn, Caliburn.Micro, ... )

Those deliver a great assistance in managing WPF applications.

In essence you need to keep a reference to the ViewModel, a collection in the mainviewmodel or mainview that keeps track of the loaded viewmodels.